# Python read from txt file (analyze food webs)

Tags: python, file

part1:

it ask to list everything that each predator eats on a single line. For example, if your file contains the lines:

```
lion eats zebra 
lion eats gazelle 
lion eats wildebeest
```

then the output should be like:

```
lion eats zebra, gazelle, and zebra
```

part2:

it ask to identify the apex predator which is the species in the food web that is not eaten by another organism.

i'm not sure how to do it plz help me thx!

Comment: Be specific with your reuirement as to what you wanna know, logic code etc??

Comment: We aren't a homework service. Post what code you have tried first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the input file is called `predators.txt` and has the following content:

```
lion eats zebra
zombie eats snow lion
lion eats gazelle
lion eats wildebeest
zombie eats brains
```

The following script produces the output:

```
lion eats zebra, gazelle, and wildebeest
zombie eats snow lion, and brains
```

If this is the output you need, you can gladly submit the following script as your homework:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
print((lambda a,_: '\n'.join
('{} eats {}'.format(b, ', '
.join(c)[::-1].replace(',',
'dna ,',1)[::-1])for b,c in
a.items()))(*(lambda a,b:(a,
[a[c].append(d)if c in a else
a.update({c:[d]})for c,_,d in
b]))({},[a.strip().split(
maxsplit=2)for a in open
('predators.txt')])))
```